# Custom Authentication Provider - extract OpenID Connect token (id_token)

Tags: authorization

I am considering implementing a [Custom Authentication provider](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm&type=5) to substitute for using the OOTB OAuth/OpenID Provider because I need to extract the `id_token` (in JWT format) from Okta but this is [not possible with the OOTB Auth Provider](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/359002/salesforce-apex-oidc-auth-provider-how-to-retrieve-id-token). Can anyone confirm if this is possible if I implement a *Custom Authentication Provider*?

Comment: It's possible in some (but not all) OIDC flows where the callback to the plugin has the id_token as represented by [`AuthProviderCallbackState`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderCallbackState).  Whether you've got one of these flows depends on the other party (the OP in OIDC lingo). Set it up and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I’ve successfully done similar using the `Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass` methods. You gain full implementation control, and the callback specifically where you can decompose the response into necessary parts and map them manually.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm

Comment: Your answers are very short and sweet, you should consider giving quite a bit more detail that answers the question, take the relevant content from the linked article and add it to your answer if this helps or provide a snippet of code.
Most of your answer are very short yes they come close to helping, but consider the value of providing content that improves the site and helps the OP.